# Perl using the special character &

Tags: perl

I had a small question. I was reading some code and as my school didn't teach me anything useful about perl programming, I am here to ask you people. I see this line being used a lot in some perl programs:

```
$variable = &something();
```

I don't know what the `&` sign means here as I never say it in perl. And the `something` is a subroutine ( I am guessing). It usually says a name and it has arguments like a function too sometimes. Can someone tell me what `&` stands for here and what that `something` is all the time.

The variable takes in some sort of returned value and is then used to check some conditions, which makes me think it is a subroutine. But still why the `&`?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In older versions of perl `&` was used to call subroutines. Now this is not necessary and `\&` is mostly used to take a `reference` to subroutine,

```
my $sub_ref = \&subroutine;
```

or to ignore function prototype (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes)

Other than for referencing subroutines `&` is `bitwise and` operator,

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And

Comment: oh so if I change it to without a & sign, it would still work?

Comment: okay. So I am not able to find the function it is pointing to. It must be in some other file. But can you tell me how they called a function from another file without using the package thing : package::sub()

Comment: I need to make one of my own...so I need some understanding

Comment: how does your script look like? you could take a reference to package method and call it via reference, `my $f = \&package::sub; $f->();`

Comment: the script looks like what I wrote in the question: $var=&funtion();

Comment: But the only way I know to call a function from another file is using something simillar to what u said...using packages

Comment: Can it be that the other programs are in the /usr/bin/perl folder and thus they don't need a package name to be called?

Comment: packages are included using `require` and `use`. didn't saw your source so it's hard to tell

Comment: Yes it does have require "file.pl" in it

Comment: So if I do require "file.pl" and that file contains my subroutine then I don't need to write package::subroutine() to call it?

Comment: @sush, The other file probably exported it. (Module: `package Module; use Exporter qw( import ); our @EXPORT = qw( foo ); sub foo { ... } 1;`, User: `use Module; foo(...);`)

Comment: oh thats pretty smart...do u have a link where I can read all this?

Comment: @ikegami - from the .pl extension and the '&foo()' in the code, I'd expect it is very old code and not to be using packages, but doing something like this: file.pl `sub foo { ... } 1;`  then `require file.pl; foo()`

Comment: @plusplus, I only read the comments quickly before posting mine. That's surely true. If so: The use of `&` there is an error, the use of `require` (instead of `do`) to load a file a package is an error, and that approach to writing a module (no package) is an error. See [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) to see how to write a module.

Comment: From what I can see -- require is better in every way than do (the docs present some cases where you can do your own error checking, but for the average use case it certainly isn't an error).

Answer (score 29):

Virtually every time you see `&` outside of `\&foo` and `EXRP && EXPR`, it's an error.

---

- `&foo(...)` is the same as `foo(...)` except `foo`'s prototype will be ignored.

  ```
  sub foo(&@) { ... }      # Cause foo to takes a BLOCK as its first arg

  foo { ... } ...;
  &foo(sub { ... }, ...);  # Same thing.
  ```

  Only subroutines (not operators) will be called by `&foo(...)`.

  ```
  sub print { ... }
  print(...);         # Calls the print builtin
  &print(...);        # Calls the print sub.
  ```

  You'll probably never need to use this feature in your entire programming career. If you see it used, it's surely someone using `&` when they shouldn't.
- `&foo` is similar to `&foo(@_)`. The difference is that changes to `@_` in `foo` affects the current sub's `@_`.

  You'll probably never need to use this feature in your entire programming career. If you see it used, it's surely someone using `&` when they shouldn't or a foolish attempt at optimization. However, the following is pretty elegant:

  ```
  sub log_info  { unshift @_, 'info';  &log }
  sub log_warn  { unshift @_, 'warn';  &log }
  sub log_error { unshift @_, 'error'; &log }
  ```
- `goto &foo` is similar to `&foo`, except the current subroutine is removed from the call stack first. This will cause it to not show up in stack traces, for example.

  You'll probably never need to use this feature in your entire programming career. If you see it used, it's surely a foolish attempt at optimization.

  ```
  sub log_info  { unshift @_, 'info';  goto &log; } # These are slower than
  sub log_warn  { unshift @_, 'warn';  goto &log; } # not using goto, but maybe
  sub log_error { unshift @_, 'error'; goto &log; } # maybe log uses caller()?
  ```
- `$&` contains what the last regex expression match matched. Before 5.20, using this causes every regex in your entire interpreter to become slower (if they have no captures), so don't use this.

  ```
  print $&        if /fo+/;     # Bad before 5.20
  print $MATCH    if /fo+/;     # Bad (Same thing. Requires "use English;")
  print ${^MATCH} if /fo+/p;    # Ok (Requires Perl 5.10)
  print $1        if /(fo+)/;   # Ok
  ```
- `defined &foo` is a perfectly legitimate way of checking if a subroutine exists, but it's not something you'll likely ever need. There's also `exists &foo` is similar, but not as useful.
- `EXPR & EXPR` is the bitwise AND operator. This is used when dealing with low-level systems that store multiple pieces of information in a single word.

  ```
  system($cmd);
  die "Can't execute command: $!\n"       if $? == -1;
  die "Child kill by ".($? & 0x7F)."\n"   if $? & 0x7F;
  die "Child exited with ".($? >> 8)."\n" if $? >> 8;
  ```
- `&{ EXPR }()` (and `&$ref()`) is a subroutine call via a reference. This is a perfectly acceptable and somewhat common thing to do, though I prefer the `$ref->()` syntax. Example in next item.
- `\&foo` takes a reference to subroutine `foo`. This is a perfectly acceptable and somewhat common thing to do.

  ```
  my %dispatch = (
     foo => \&foo,
     bar => \&bar,
  );

  my $handler = $dispatch{$cmd} or die;
  $handler->();
  # Same:  &{ $handler }();
  # Same:  &$handler();
  ```
- `EXPR && EXPR` is the boolean AND operator. I'm sure you're familiar with this extremely common operator.

  ```
  if (0 <= $x && $x <= 100) { ... }
  ```

Comment: This should be `&` usage for dereferincing? `perl -E '&{sub{ say pop }}( 4 )'`

Comment: @mpapec, Yes, though I prefer `sub { say pop }->( 4 )`. Added.

Comment: Note: Sublanguages (e.g. prototypes, regex patterns) may also use `&`.