# Perl - Difference between invoking sub-routine with or without "&" (ampersand)

Tags: perl, subroutine

What is the difference between the next two lines in Perl:

```
PopupMsg("Hello");

&PopupMsg("Hello");

...

sub PopupMsg
{
    subroutines code here...
}
```

please notice that in some cases I must use the first line and in some the second, other wise I get an error.

Comment: Please give an example of when you have to use the second form.

Comment: [Perl using the special character &](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173783/perl-using-the-special-character/17173958#17173958)

Answer (score 9):

It is bad practice to call subroutines using the ampersand `&`. The call will compile fine if you use parentheses or have predeclared the symbol as a subroutine name.

The ampersand is necessary when you are dealing with the subroutine as a data item, for instance, to take a reference to it.

```
my $sub_ref = \&PopupMsg;
$sub_ref->(); # calling subroutine as reference.
```

Comment: It's also necessary when you have a subroutine that's the same name as a Perl operator. The `&` form will always call the user-defined subroutine. For example, many people in my Perl classes start the first of second day with `sub log {}` to output something because they haven't seen that `log` is a builtin for math. The answer is to not do that, but, Perl is also adding new operator names too.

Answer (score 4):

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html:

```
NAME(LIST);  # & is optional with parentheses.
NAME LIST;   # Parentheses optional if predeclared/imported.
&NAME(LIST); # Circumvent prototypes.
&NAME;       # Makes current @_ visible to called subroutine.
```

Prototypes explained further down in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes.